# Explanation of the working of the feedback circuit in an SMPS power supply

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply

I need explanation of the working of the feedback circuit in an SMPS power supply. What are the purposes of the R1, Z1 and R2 in this circuit? How does the circuit protect (short circuit protection) when the output is accidentally shorted? Can I short the output of the opto-isolator IC to test if the hot side is working or not? How does the value of current in the photo-transistor in the optocoupler influence the pwm ?

[image]